# MS Excel mouse-scroll-down is skipping rows. Possible to make it scroll down like the keyboard's go-down button?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I am using MS Excel version 2016. Each cell contains tens of lines, so height is long. When it's like this, when I scroll down my mouse, it often skips a row. If I press down the keyboard's go-down button, it just gradually goes down. But of course it's not convenient. How can I fix how my mouse works?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the mouse wheel will scroll about three rows at a time.

You need to modify the mouse settings in the control panel：

[image]

Comment: That's not the problem. This affects every other things. My problem is only with MS Excel. If I make the same table on MS Word, my mouse scrolls down continuously. But on MS Excel, it just jumps over to row by row. So when row is very high, it's a problem.